# VBA data type to store Range().Characters()

Tags: vba

I can't find a data type to store `Characters` from a `Range`.

I already tried the following code, but nothing happened. I think the problem is because of wrong data type.

```
Dim chars As Characters
chars = Range("A2").Characters(0, 4)
MsgBox chars.Text
```

Comment: It's not a `String`?

Comment: No, It is a collection of characters. It has a `.Text` property to get `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `set` the variable and the index is **1** based not **0**

```
Dim chars As Characters
Set chars = Range("A2").Characters(1, 4)

chars.Font.Color = vbRed
```